# Running two loops at same time and displaying its length value

Tags: java, android, loops

I know how loop works, but today I got stuck and have no idea on how to handle loop in such situation. As I am developing apps in Android. I have two string-array lets say name_collection and meaning_collection; I have no problem on passing one textView and calling it like below

```
<string-array name="name_collection">
<item>name_one</item>
<item>name_two</item>
<item>name_three</item>


<string-array name="meaning_collection">
<item>meaning_one</item>
<item>meaning_two</item>
<item>meaning_three</item>
```

and called all items like

```
public void initializeData() {
    names = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < nameCollection.length;i++){
            names.add(new Name(nameCollection[i]+"  "));
        }
    }
```

Above code is for one paramerter, which displays list in cardview for name_collection as name_one, name_two and name_three.

Now, I need to passed the meaning below name_collection serially in same cardView. For that the parameter takes like:

```
 public void initializeData() {
names = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < nameCollection.length;i++){
        names.add(new Name(nameCollection[i]+"  ", Parameter_for_meaning_collection));
    }
}
```

I should give parameter like meaningCollection[i] but where should I compare?

Comment: Where should you compare what?

Comment: I want to do is names.add(new Name(nameCollection[i]+"  ", meaningCollection[j]+"  ")); where j should compare the meaningCollection.length like j<meaningCollection.length; in the same loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment below, you could do something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nameCollection.length; i++){
        if(i < meaningCollection.length) {
            names.add(new Name(nameCollection[i] + "  ",
                meaningCollection[i] + "  "));
        } else {
            names.add(new Name(nameCollection[i] + "  ",
                "no meaning"));
            // replace "no meaning" with whatever default value you'd like
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, Let me make you clear, I have already displayed the nameCollection in my app before and there's about 1000 list  and  now I realize of adding  a meaning of it, and  gave  one  more parameter meanCollection to it. Although later the  size will be same but for now in developing  I will not  add those list at one time and run them. So, to make it testing, I need to return the actual size of meaningcollection. And sorry, for poor english. I can't explain the right way..Thank you